# what to return in onStartCommand for a service

Tags: java, android

I have been looking through the documentation and sometimes the `onStartCommand()` returns `START_NOT_STICKY`, sometimes it returns the following:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

I am now confused as to why some services return `super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It all depends on what you want. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) says:

> For backwards compatibility, the default implementation calls onStart(Intent, int) and returns either START_STICKY or
>   START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY.

So returning `super.onStartCommand()` is equivalent to returning `START_STICKY`. If you don't want the default behavior you can return another constant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I have one query.. If I have not override `onStartCommand()` in my Service, then by default what value will be returned? How system will treat my Service for re-starts/stopping??

Comment: I think it will return `START_STICKY`

Answer (score 4):

The most often used are

- Service.START_STICKY
- Service.START_NOT_STICKY and
- Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT

Service.START_STICKY will restart if the android system terminates for any reason.
Service.START_NOT_STICKY will run till it has pending works.
Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT is similar to Service.START_STICKY but the original Intent is re-delivered to the onStartCommand method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Service.START_STICKY
>> the system restarts the service with everything refresh not using the previous intent. 
Service.START_NOT_STICKY 
>> the system does not restarts the service.
Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT
>>the system restarts the service with using the previous intent.`enter code here
```