# Android background service works slower when phone in sleep mode or app hidden for a some long time

Tags: java, android, service, background, location

I write an android native app that asks for LatLng coordinate periodically.

So, I have MainActivity class, where the UI runs. And here I initiate a background service, using Intent:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // here are defined required methods like OnCreate() etc.

    Intent locTaskIntent = new Intent(this, LocationsTaskService.class);
    startService(locTaskIntent);

    // ...
}
```

A Service, being initiated by *onStartCommand()*, schedules asynchronous tasks periodically:

```
public class LocationsTaskService extends Service {
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer taskTimer = new Timer();
    TimerTask asyncTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run () {
                    LocationProcessor LocationProcessor = new LocationProcessor(mContext, ++counter);
                    LocationProcessor.startRoutine();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    taskTimer.schedule(asyncTask, 0, RConstants.locUpdateInterval);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startid);
}
```

Where the *startRoutine()* method of *LocationProcessor* class performs operations for android os to request locations, and then waits for an answer in *callback* method, implemented in *LocationListener* or cancels the search by timeout:

```
private class LocationProcessor {

    // ....

    LocationProcessor(Context context, int sessionId) {
        mLocManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mSessionId = sessionId;
    }

    public void startRoutine() {
        // The CountDownTimer is used to break locations search by timeout
        cdTimer = new CountDownTimer(RConstants.locUpdateTimeoutUsed, RConstants.locUpdateTimeoutUsed ) {
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    // cancel updates listening
                    mLocManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
                    mLocManager = null;
                }
            }.start();
        // requesting for location updates
        mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDTS,
                    MIN_DIST_CHANGE_FOR_UPDTS,
                    locationListener
            );
    }

private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        cdTimer.cancel();
        cdTimer = null;
        mLocManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        mLocManager = null;
    }
}
```

And *Manifest* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.location.devsname.appname">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".LocationsTaskService">

        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**The problems are:**

1. App works fine until the phone fall asleep for a some long time and / or app being hidden.

When I wake the phone, I can see the following picture (red marks are related to state, when phone sleeps, and, for opposite state - green marks, when messages receive promptly):

[image: app's screenshot]

2. When I launch some number of memory consuming apps in phone (it has only 512 MB RAM), I receive message from System like: "Sorry, ..the app name.., has stopped". It seems like the OS tends to free memory for new loading apps, killing the old processes - *it's my guess*. How can I forcibly say to the System to care it running?

Comment: You should go with AlarmManager in low RAM devices. Because it's  system priority to kill background service. So just fire an alarm to find out that your service is running or not if it's not running then start it again and continue alarm. And delay of code execution will be there due to system priority task.

Comment: @ReadyAndroid, Great! With using AlarmManager my code is much shorter and looks much more pretty! And the most important, it works faultlessly in background: even if UI reloads, alarm is still firing as been scheduled! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

For your 2nd point, I believe returning `START_STICKY` from your `onStartCommand` will do the trick.

From the documentation

> int START_STICKY
>
> Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int): if this
>   service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from
>   onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the started state
>   but don't retain this delivered intent. Later the system will try to
>   re-create the service. Because it is in the started state, it will
>   guarantee to call onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) after creating the
>   new service instance; if there are not any pending start commands to
>   be delivered to the service, it will be called with a null intent
>   object, so you must take care to check for this.
>
> This mode makes sense for things that will be explicitly started and stopped to run for arbitrary periods of time, such as a service performing background music playback.

Comment: As I understand, I should
`return START_STICKY;`
But how to deal with
`return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startid);`
that I use to return now?
Suppose, I should call the method from superclass?

Comment: here is said that super.onStartCommand is equivalent to START_STICKY
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21941792/3805544